# OMP Settings issue

Tags: openmp

**1.** I checked out oneDNN v1.2

**2.** Build it using clang

```
export CC=clang and export CXX=clang++
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake ..
make -j
sudo make install
```

**3.** modified getting_started.cpp to add a print as first line inside main() function

```
(base) ratan@dattonaxq1648:~/my_work/oneDNN/examples$ git diff
diff --git a/examples/getting_started.cpp b/examples/getting_started.cpp
index 2376013eb..3c43dab91 100644
--- a/examples/getting_started.cpp
+++ b/examples/getting_started.cpp
@@ -469,6 +469,7 @@ void getting_started_tutorial(engine::kind engine_kind) {
/// @snippet getting_started.cpp Main
// [Main]
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

std::cout << "Start of getting_started code\n";
int exit_code = 0;
```

**4.** export these env variables for verbose

```
export KMP_AFFINITY=verbose
export OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE
export KMP_SETTINGS=TRUE
```

**5.** build examples/getting_started.cpp

```
clang++ -std=c++11 getting_started.cpp -o bin/getting_started_cpp -L/usr/local/lib -ldnnl
```

**6.** Run above test

```
(base) ratan@dattonaxq1648:~/my_work/oneDNN/examples$ ./bin/getting_started_cpp

User settings:

   KMP_AFFINITY=verbose
   KMP_SETTINGS=TRUE
   OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE

Effective settings:

   KMP_ABORT_DELAY=0
   KMP_ADAPTIVE_LOCK_PROPS='1,1024'
   KMP_ALIGN_ALLOC=64
   KMP_ALL_THREADPRIVATE=384
   KMP_ATOMIC_MODE=2
   KMP_BLOCKTIME=200
   KMP_CPUINFO_FILE: value is not defined
   KMP_DETERMINISTIC_REDUCTION=false
   KMP_DEVICE_THREAD_LIMIT=2147483647
   KMP_DISP_NUM_BUFFERS=7
   KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=false
   KMP_ENABLE_TASK_THROTTLING=true
   KMP_FORCE_REDUCTION: value is not defined
   KMP_FOREIGN_THREADS_THREADPRIVATE=true
   KMP_FORKJOIN_BARRIER='2,2'
   KMP_FORKJOIN_BARRIER_PATTERN='hyper,hyper'
   KMP_FORKJOIN_FRAMES=true
   KMP_FORKJOIN_FRAMES_MODE=3
   KMP_GTID_MODE=3
   KMP_HANDLE_SIGNALS=false
   KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL=1
   KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MODE=0
   KMP_INIT_AT_FORK=true
   KMP_ITT_PREPARE_DELAY=0
   KMP_LIBRARY=throughput
   KMP_LOCK_KIND=queuing
   KMP_MALLOC_POOL_INCR=1M
   KMP_NUM_LOCKS_IN_BLOCK=1
   KMP_PLAIN_BARRIER='2,2'
   KMP_PLAIN_BARRIER_PATTERN='hyper,hyper'
   KMP_REDUCTION_BARRIER='1,1'
   KMP_REDUCTION_BARRIER_PATTERN='hyper,hyper'
   KMP_SCHEDULE='static,balanced;guided,iterative'
   KMP_SETTINGS=true
   KMP_SPIN_BACKOFF_PARAMS='4096,100'
   KMP_STACKOFFSET=64
   KMP_STACKPAD=0
   KMP_STACKSIZE=8M
   KMP_STORAGE_MAP=false
   KMP_TASKING=2
   KMP_TASKLOOP_MIN_TASKS=0
   KMP_TASK_STEALING_CONSTRAINT=1
   KMP_TEAMS_THREAD_LIMIT=96
   KMP_TOPOLOGY_METHOD=all
   KMP_USE_YIELD=1
   KMP_VERSION=false
   KMP_WARNINGS=true
   OMP_AFFINITY_FORMAT='OMP: pid %P tid %i thread %n bound to OS proc set {%A}'
   OMP_ALLOCATOR=omp_default_mem_alloc
   OMP_CANCELLATION=false
   OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE=0
   OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY=false
   OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true
   OMP_DYNAMIC=false
   OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=1
   OMP_MAX_TASK_PRIORITY=0
   OMP_NESTED: deprecated; max-active-levels-var=1
   OMP_NUM_THREADS: value is not defined
   OMP_PLACES: value is not defined
   OMP_PROC_BIND='false'
   OMP_SCHEDULE='static'
   OMP_STACKSIZE=8M
   OMP_TARGET_OFFLOAD=DEFAULT
   OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=2147483647
   OMP_TOOL=enabled
   OMP_TOOL_LIBRARIES: value is not defined
   OMP_WAIT_POLICY=PASSIVE
   KMP_AFFINITY='verbose,warnings,respect,granularity=core,none'


OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
   _OPENMP='201611'
  [host] OMP_AFFINITY_FORMAT='OMP: pid %P tid %i thread %n bound to OS proc set {%A}'
  [host] OMP_ALLOCATOR='omp_default_mem_alloc'
  [host] OMP_CANCELLATION='FALSE'
  [host] OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE='0'
  [host] OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY='FALSE'
  [host] OMP_DISPLAY_ENV='TRUE'
  [host] OMP_DYNAMIC='FALSE'
  [host] OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS='1'
  [host] OMP_MAX_TASK_PRIORITY='0'
  [host] OMP_NESTED: deprecated; max-active-levels-var=1
  [host] OMP_NUM_THREADS: value is not defined
  [host] OMP_PLACES: value is not defined
  [host] OMP_PROC_BIND='false'
  [host] OMP_SCHEDULE='static'
  [host] OMP_STACKSIZE='8M'
  [host] OMP_TARGET_OFFLOAD=DEFAULT
  [host] OMP_THREAD_LIMIT='2147483647'
  [host] OMP_TOOL='enabled'
  [host] OMP_TOOL_LIBRARIES: value is not defined
  [host] OMP_WAIT_POLICY='PASSIVE'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END


OMP: Info #211: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #209: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-95
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 96 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 2 packages x 24 cores/pkg x 2 threads/core (48 total cores)
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6193 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0-95
Start of getting_started code
dnnl_verbose,info,DNNL v1.2.0 (commit 75d0b1a7f3586c212e37acebbb8acd221cee7216)
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,runtime:OpenMP
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,isa:Intel AVX2
dnnl_verbose,info,gpu,runtime:none
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6194 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6195 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6196 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6197 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6198 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6199 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6200 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6201 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6202 thread 9 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6203 thread 10 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6205 thread 12 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6204 thread 11 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6206 thread 13 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6207 thread 14 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6208 thread 15 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6209 thread 16 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6210 thread 17 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6211 thread 18 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6212 thread 19 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6213 thread 20 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6214 thread 21 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6215 thread 22 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6217 thread 24 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6216 thread 23 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6218 thread 25 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6219 thread 26 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6220 thread 27 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6221 thread 28 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6222 thread 29 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6223 thread 30 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6224 thread 31 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6225 thread 32 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6226 thread 33 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6227 thread 34 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6228 thread 35 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6229 thread 36 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6230 thread 37 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6231 thread 38 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6233 thread 40 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6232 thread 39 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6235 thread 42 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6234 thread 41 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6236 thread 43 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6237 thread 44 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6238 thread 45 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6239 thread 46 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6240 thread 47 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6241 thread 48 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6242 thread 49 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6243 thread 50 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6244 thread 51 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6246 thread 53 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6245 thread 52 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6248 thread 55 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6247 thread 54 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6249 thread 56 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6250 thread 57 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6251 thread 58 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6252 thread 59 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6254 thread 61 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6253 thread 60 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6255 thread 62 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6256 thread 63 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6257 thread 64 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6258 thread 65 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6259 thread 66 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6260 thread 67 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6261 thread 68 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6262 thread 69 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6263 thread 70 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6264 thread 71 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6265 thread 72 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6266 thread 73 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6267 thread 74 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6268 thread 75 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6269 thread 76 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6270 thread 77 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6271 thread 78 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6272 thread 79 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6273 thread 80 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6274 thread 81 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6275 thread 82 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6276 thread 83 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6277 thread 84 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6278 thread 85 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6279 thread 86 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6280 thread 87 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6281 thread 88 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6282 thread 89 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6283 thread 90 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6285 thread 92 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6284 thread 91 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6286 thread 93 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6288 thread 95 bound to OS proc set 0-95
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6287 thread 94 bound to OS proc set 0-95
dnnl_verbose,exec,cpu,eltwise,jit:avx2,forward_inference,data_f32::blocked:acdb:f0 diff_undef::undef::f0,,alg:eltwise_relu alpha:0 beta:0,1x3x13x13,32.114
Example passed on CPU.
```

**7.** If we see that thread 0 is created before 1st line in main() is executed.

```
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6193 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0-95
Start of getting_started code
dnnl_verbose,info,DNNL v1.2.0 (commit 75d0b1a7f3586c212e37acebbb8acd221cee7216)
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,runtime:OpenMP
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,isa:Intel AVX2
dnnl_verbose,info,gpu,runtime:none
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6194 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 0-95
```

**8.** Asked same question mkl-dnn forum and i was suggested to ask here. Tried with other mkl-dnn version (V1.3, v1.2.1, v1.2.2) and it has same behaviour.
Question:

**9.** Question.
What build setting / or run time env variable to use so that thread bounds happens after entering main()
Expected behavior:

```
Start of getting_started code 

OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6193 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0-95
dnnl_verbose,info,DNNL v1.2.0 (commit 75d0b1a7f3586c212e37acebbb8acd221cee7216)
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,runtime:OpenMP
dnnl_verbose,info,cpu,isa:Intel AVX2
dnnl_verbose,info,gpu,runtime:none
OMP: Info #249: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6193 tid 6194 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 0-95
```

Comment: Thread 0 is the main thread of the program, a.k.a. the OpenMP master thread, and the OpenMP runtime is applying the binding policy in the DSO constructor before the invocation of `main()`. I don't see the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev for the comment. I have olde code base of mkl-dnn which is behaving like expected behavior. And older code is performing better. So question is how to control OpenMP runtime is applying the binding policy before invocation of main or after invocation of main()?

Comment: Your threads get bound to all CPU cores (assuming you have 48 CPU cores in total with HT), therefore whether the binding policy is applied before `main()` is called or when the first OpenMP parallel region is created has no influence on the performance. You should look somewhere else for the culprit.

Comment: @HristoIlievThanks, you are right. Culprit could be something else. I will look from that angle. But trying to understand how to find out what changed in code so that binding policy is applied when the first OpenMP parallel region is created compared to new code where binding policy is applied before main() is called. 
Performance issue comes later when GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY is  used with new code.
Can some part of new code change the binding policy rule so that binding policy is applied before main? If yes, what kind of code pattern to look for?

Comment: More info: I have 24 parallel region, new code is creating 0 to 24 (25 threads)
(new code)
`OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 7998 tid 7998 thread 0 bound to OS proc set {0}`
<main>
<parallel region>
`OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 7998 tid 8049 thread 1 bound to OS proc set {1}
.
.
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 7998 tid 8072 thread 23 bound to OS proc set {23}
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 7998 tid 8071 thread 22 bound to OS proc set {22}
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 7998 tid 8073 thread 24 bound to OS proc set {0}`

Comment: With old code, 24 threads are created:
(old code)
<main>
<parallel region>
`OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12270 tid 12321 thread 0 bound to OS proc set {0}
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12270 tid 12323 thread 2 bound to OS proc set {2}
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12270 tid 12322 thread 1 bound to OS proc set {1}
.
.
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12270 tid 12343 thread 22 bound to OS proc set {22}
OMP: Info #242: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12270 tid 12344 thread 23 bound to OS proc set {23}`

Comment: Things that execute before `main()` are DSO (library) constructors and constructors of static C++ objects. The former you can find looking for `__attribute__((constructor))` in the function definition. The later are objects defined in the global scope or static class members.

Comment: By the way, I checked out oneDNN and built the v1.2 branch (commit 75d0b1a7f3586c212e37acebbb8acd221cee7216, same as yours) with Clang 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 and the `getting_started` binary behaves the way you want it to, i.e., the binding policy is applied from within `main()`. Perhaps you have a different version of the OpenMP runtime.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev that was really helpful. Some global variables were found in oneDNN v1.2:
`unsigned int LLC_cache_size = get_cache_size(3, false); `
Is there any command which can be run on generated .so file to print/list:
1.  DSO (library) constructors
2.  objects defined in the global scope or static class members
Really appreciate your help.
Yes, it is same commit id, I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and different version of clang

Comment: I doubt the problem is in DNN then.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks. Do you think problem could be in DNN if new version has some global variable declared?

Comment: As I said, I compiled the exact same version you did and got the old behaviour you described. So the problem is not in DNN.

Comment: @HristoIliev with clang 9.0.0 and its OpenMP library oneDNN v1.2, i get old behavior too. I am using priority clang 9.0.0 (modified by our team), and issue is reproducible (new behaviour). I am able to fix it by changing global variable which was getting initialized by calling functions.
E.g. L1_cache_size in src/cpu/jit_avx512_common_conv_winograd_kernel_f32.cpp


`-unsigned int L1_cache_size = get_cache_size(1, true);`
`+unsigned int L1_cache_size() {`
`+    return get_cache_size(1, true);`
`+}`
`+unsigned int L2_cache_size() {`
`+   return get_cache_size(2, true);`

Comment: Converting these global variables to functions calls in below files helped to get the old behaviour;
src/cpu/jit_avx512_common_conv_kernel.cpp
src/cpu/jit_avx512_common_conv_winograd_kernel_f32.cpp
src/cpu/jit_avx512_common_convolution_winograd.cpp
src/cpu/jit_avx512_core_f32_wino_conv_4x3_kernel.cpp
Thanks for pointing out where to look for :) @HristoIliev